# how to fill textbox with property in collection?

Tags: events, collections, combobox, textbox, textchanged

I have a List collection an entity with

salary,desgn,salaryId, salary_basis,

from here I want to  fill the textbox at textchanged event, the desgn,salaryId, and salary basis

i queried from db and filled the collection. I have done it with entity but cant do with collection....

Any suggestions....

emdad,

Comment: This sounds a bit like ASP.NET. What language are you working in?

Answer (score 0):

Emdad why not use loop to work on each element of the collection.suppose you collection have more than one element ,on loop just take one by one element then work on it,what ever you want .Hope this solve your problem

Comment: I have used loop in this manner, I have the idea but syntax is not right, please suggest the correction in my foreach, foreach (entity item in collection)
            {
                txtSalaryId.Text = Convert.ToString(entity.SalaryId);
                txtDsg.Text = Convert.ToString(entity.Desgn);
                lblMonthly_Hourly_Basis.Text = entity.SalaryBasis.ToString();
            }

Comment: Why not use var instead on entity or use the collection type. foreach (var item in collection) ,hope this solve your problem,don't forget to accept the ans....

Comment: was actually solved before the last refrence......appreciate...your brilliantfeedback...:)